# Why args passed to script through ENTRYPOINT is not received properly?

Tags: bash, docker, shell, dockerfile

The `startup.sh` script for my node.js project is:

```sh
#!bin/sh

echo "Starting with ENV: $ENV"
cd /app

export PORT=8080
export NODE_ENV=$ENV

node main.js $ENV
```

The Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM ...
LABLE ..

ARG env
ENV ENV=${env}

RUN mkdir /app

# COPY required files
COPY ...

RUN cd /app && npm install --silent
EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "/app/startup.sh"]
```

I'm building the image using Jenkins with command:

```sh
docker build --build-arg ENV=test -t "tag" .
```

The script is failing to receive the value "test".

What I tried:

- Updating `startup.sh` to use `$1`(positional arg) instead of `$ENV` and pass the value through ENTRYPOINT:

  - `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "/app/startup.sh", ${ENV}]` 
    This gives error: file or directory not found: /bin/sh /bin/sh,]
  - `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "/app/startup.sh", "${ENV}"]` 
    Doesn't give error but value of `$1` is "${ENV}"
- Use combination of ENTRYPOINT and CMD:

  - `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "/app/startup.sh"]` and `CMD[${ENV}]`
    The value of $1 is coming as "-c".

Comment: Try to change `#!bin/sh` to `#! /bin/sh` in your `startup.sh` ?

Comment: Does the `echo` line in the script print out?  How are you accessing the parameter in your code?  (Can you use `process.env.NODE_ENV` or `process.env.ENV` instead of a positional parameter?)

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes, the `echo` line prints: "Starting with ENV: ". I thought of using process.env.ENV, but the env is required at boot-up time. For ex: the `config` lib requires NODE_ENV so it can load appropriate yaml file (test/stage/prod).

Answer (score -1):

I think it's because of the use of `ARG env`

```
ARG ENV
ENV ENV=${ENV}
```